# Installing Visual Studio 2005 on same machine that has Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, windows-xp

is there any harm if go installing VS 2005 (only C++ Compiler) on which VS 2010 is currently installed? Does it overwrite any shared files?

Comment: No one can give you a definitive answer. I've done it several times myself without experiencing any problems, but the official recommendation is to always install Visual Studio versions in sequence. If you choose to do something else, there are risks involved, minimal though they may be.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed Visual Studio 2005 and 2010 in my PC. No harm done. Make sure you don't run your 2005 .sln or project files on 2010. Or it will convert them. Make sure what version you are using while programming.

Answer (score 1):

No, will have no harm if you install and Visual Studio 2005

Comment: Do you have any source or documentation that confirms this? Even something like "I've done it myself twice and it worked"?

Answer (score 1):

No you can completely install Studio 6, 2003, 2005, 2010, etc. parallel with no harm.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question that is being asked. Installing the versions in release order is an entirely different proposition than installing an older version when you already have a newer version installed.

Comment: I just installed Studio 6 while 2005 and 2010 were installed.